# Printing values of struct do not show correct values

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my code:

```
struct mys {
    double d[128];
};

int main() {
    int iters = 2;
    struct mys a[iters];

    for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
        a[i].d[0] = (double)i;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
        printf("%f\n", a[0].d[j]);
    }
}
```

When I run this, these are some of the middle values:

```
0.000000 11711905921668651127245114035463936382624607367372861618952521785051367817533820282282998171146926539504166684405188272240881137800884065610400809119241048416797589504.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

and printing `a[1]` shows a `-0.000` in the middle too. Why is this?

Comment: Do not delete question and post the same ones if you do not like comments, downvotes or close votes!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was asked 10 minutes ago, deleted then asked again. It is a very bad habit, waste of our time commenting and reading. I am going to to flag it for the mods attention. IMO it is worse than not very polite comment as it shows disrespect to  other community members

Comment: There's no `a[2]`. The valid array indexes are `0` and `1`.

Comment: @user2719875 You're supposed to edit the question, not delete and repost.

Comment: @Barmar Should `struct mys a[2]`  have `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]`?

Comment: No. `a[2]` means there are two elements in the array.

Comment: That's why you use `i < iters` and not `i <= iters` when filling in the array.

Comment: @Barmar Are they a[0] and a[1]? Becuase when I print a[0] elements, it also has weird elements in the middle: `0.000000
11711905921668651127245114035463936382624607367372861618952521785051367817533820282282998171146926539504166684405188272240881137800884065610400809119241048416797589504.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
`. and `a[1]` has a `-0.000` in the middle too. I will edit the question with this information.

Comment: Yes, they're `a[0]` and `a[1]`. In your first `for` loop, you only fill in `a[0].d[0]` and `a[1].d[0]`. So all the other elements will have garbage.

Comment: What are you expecting it to print for all the `d` elements that you didn't fill in?

Comment: @Barmar Ah ok I see. I thought they get initialized to 0. I wrote a for loop before this program (before setting any value of `a[0]`) and it ended up printing all 0s if I remember correctly. That's why I thought they would all be 0s.

Comment: Static variables are initialized to zero by default, automatic variables aren't initialized by default. If you got zeroes in another test, it just coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialization code is wrong. You have an array on the stack `struct mys` declared as size 2 and you <strike>index into it with larger sizes</strike> (after edit) access uninitialized members. This is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Use a nested for loop to initialize like so:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
        /* since we have a struct with an array, initialize each element using a nested for loop. */
        for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
            a[i].d[j] = (double)i;
        }
    }
```

It's possible you intended this nested for loop instead (each element different value):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
        /* since we have a struct with an array, initialize each element using a nested for loop. */
        for(int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
            a[i].d[j] = (double)j;
        }
    }
```

Comment: He's edited the question, he changed `a[2]` to `a[0]`, so he's not indexing with a larger size.

Comment: @Barmar: Ah I see. Point of nested loop still stands.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Or he could zero-initialize it with `struct mys a[iter] = {};`

Comment: @Barmar: He could. I didn't think either of his tries were trying to zero initialize or I would have considered `memset` longer than I did.

Comment: @Barmar  `struct mys a[iter] = {};` led to "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized"

Comment: @chux one hour ago you had a right opposite opinion, and you were instructing me that `= {0}` is enough